# How can I resolve this type error in python with the use of Tkinter for my app?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, types, self-reference

Whenever I use the program to try and login I receive this error back:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
TypeError: LoginCheck() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Below is a snippet of my code, I'm sorry for it being long but I don't know how much I need to show exactly for the problem to be resolved easily.

```
class Log(tkinter.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.userEnt = tkinter.Entry(self, width=50, justify="center", foreground="#000000", background="#FFFFFF")
    self.userEnt.insert(0, "USERNAME")
    self.userEnt.place(relx=0.26, rely=0.346)

    self.passEnt = tkinter.Entry(self, width=50, show="*", justify="center", foreground="#000000", background="#FFFFFF")
    # passEnt.background = "#FFFFFF"
    self.passEnt.insert(0, "PASSWORD")
    self.passEnt.place(relx=0.26, rely=0.413)

    self.logBtn = tkinter.Button(self, text="login", bg="#383A39", fg="#AB97BD", width=15, height=3,
                                 command=Log.LoginCheck)

    self.logBtn.place(relx=0.70, rely=0.346)

    self.createUserBtn = tkinter.Button(self, text="New User", bg="#383A39", fg="#AB97BD", width=15, height=2,
                                   command=lambda: controller.show_frame(NewUser))

    self.createUserBtn.place(relx=0.835, rely=0.925)

def LoginCheck(self):
    global press

    if press >= 1:

        c.execute("SELECT * FROM Users")
        list_of_users = (c.fetchall())
        # print(list_of_users)  Uncomment to print everything in the user table as a list
        position = 0
        for _ in list_of_users:
            user = list_of_users[position]
            if self.userEnt.get() == user[3] and self.passEnt.get() == user[4]:
                print("Welcome,", user[1])
                print("ID:", user[0])
                print("First Name:", user[1])
                print("Last Name:", user[2])
                print("User Name:", user[3])
                print("Password:", user[4])
                app.mainloop()
            elif self.userEnt.get() != user[3] and self.passEnt.get() != user[4]:
                self.userEnt.delete(0, "END")
                self.userEnt.insert(0, "The details entered are the wrong username and password")
            elif self.userEnt.get() != user[3] and self.passEnt.get() == user[4]:
                print("Incorrect username")
                print(user)
                print(press - 1)
                self.userEnt.delete(0, "END")
                self.userEnt.insert(0, "Enter the correct username please. " + str(press - 1) + "/" + str(
                    5) + " tries left")
                press -= 1
            elif self.userEnt.get() == user[3] and self.passEnt.get() != user[4]:
                print("Incorrect password")
                print(user)
                print(press - 1)
                self.userEnt.delete(0, "END")
                self.userEnt.insert(0, "Enter the correct password please. " + str(press - 1) + "/" + str(
                    5) + " tries left")
                press -= 1
            else:
                position += 1

            # The commented code below was the fixed way of logging in via "username" and "password"
            '''
            if userEnt.get() == "username" and passEnt.get() == password:
                menuWindow()
            else:
                print("Incorrect username/password")
                print(press+1) # One is added for readability and easier understanding for debugging
                userEnt.delete(0, END)
                userEnt.insert(0, "Enter the correct details please. " + str(press+1) + "/" + str(5) + " tries left")
                press += 1
            '''

    if press == 1:
        self.userEnt.delete(0, "END")
        self.userEnt.insert(0, "One attempt left. A 20 second ban is imminent.")
    if press == 0:
        self.userEnt.state = "readonly"
        self.passEnt.state = "readonly"
        time.sleep(20)
        press = 5
        self.userEnt.state = "ENABLED"
        self.passEnt.state = "ENABLED"
        self.userEnt.delete(0, "END")
        self.userEnt.insert(0, "Username")
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this, please respond *thumbs up*
P.S. I'm a noob when it comes to python, I have been using tutorials but I understand to a certain degree how most things work.

Comment: Please read and follow the instructions here: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: the error is in this line  `self.logBtn = tkinter.Button(self, text="login", bg="#383A39", fg="#AB97BD", width=15, height=3,
                                 command=Log.LoginCheck)`
It should be `Log.LoginCheck()`

Comment: @Somar: no, that is not what the command should be.

Comment: `Log.LoginCheck` is a function

Comment: @Somar no it's an unbound method, but that's not the point anyway - the `command` argument of a `tkinter.Button` expects a callable so passing it a function would be ok (Python functions are objects you know ?). The problem here is passing an unbound method, which when called rightly complains about not getting it's first positional argument.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
self.logBtn = tkinter.Button(
   self, text="login", bg="#383A39",  
   fg="#AB97BD", width=15, height=3,
   command=Log.LoginCheck
   )
```

you are passing an unbound method. Unbound methods need to be explicitely passed the current instance as first argument (because, not being called on an instance, they cannot inject the current instance as first argument at call time).

What you want obviously is to pass the `self.LoginCheck` bound method instead.

Comment: Thank you for the help; it seems like i have to research unbound, bound and methods/ functions. As you have seen part of my code, are there any improvements that you think I could make in general? If so please do tell me. Thanks again.

Comment: There's indeed room for improvement but SO is the right place for this - you may want to post on codereview instead (once your code is working that is). But you should at least make "press" an attribute of your object instead of a global - part of the point of OO is to avoid globals.